# Cannot uninstall Numpy due to pip problem

Tags: python, numpy, pip, raspberry-pi, installation

I'm trying to remove Numpy on a Raspberry Pi 4 machine (Rasbian) but can't figure it out. I got a Permission Denied error when I output:

`pip uninstall numpy`

I tried with root privilege but got a `pip: command not found` error.

As very often the problem seems to be related to pip installation, so I tried to reinstall it. First when I check pip version with `pip -V` I got:

`pip 20.0.2 from /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)`

So I guess pip is install locally for the user but not for root. I removed everything using apt:

```
sudo apt remove python-pip python3-pip python-numpy python3-numpy
```

But pip is not removed, when I issue `pip -V` I still got pip version and location on the console.

any idea where to look for for debugging this?

P.S.: there is nothing special in .bashrc, just a `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

P.P.S: Python and Python" are in /usr/bin/

P.P.P.S: I'm trying to uninstall Numpy because when I'm importing it I receive the following error:

```
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.7 from "/usr/bin/python3",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.18.2" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.

Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What commands did you use to install numpy?

Comment: `pip install numpy` but Numpy was installed before I got the computer, I user may have installed it with `sudo`(that often leads to problems).